# AWS EFS get file last access time

Tags: amazon-web-services, filesystems, amazon-efs

As part of AWS EFS I can configure a lifecycle rule for moving files to "Standard - Infrequent Access" after "X days since last access".

If I want to implement something similar of my own. How can I check when a file was last accessed?

How can I check whether a specific file is currently in "Standard" or "Standard - Infrequent Access"

Answer (score 0):

On a local filesystem on your computer, you can `stat` the file to get all timestamps including the last access time. But if you want to monitor changes continuously, you can use the `inotify` api + a local database and build a service that moves files between say two folders *Standard* and *Infrequent* if the file wasn't say accessed in X days.

I don't know the internals of it but for a distributed file system like the EFS, I imagine they have implemented some form of tiering service that moves files between different storage types (slow/fast etc.) based on the rules. It would need to capture the access patterns as and when the files are created/read/written to/deleted in real time with some combination of in-memory records + a distributed DB to persist this information and a service that queries this DB to migrates files to and fro based on the lifecycle rules you set.